# MacOS Code Signing of bundled JDK7 on Mavericks 10.9.1

Tags: java, code-signing, osx-mavericks

I have a Java 7 application which I turn into a MacOS App following the instructions on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html.

This is no longer working. The signing still works (I use a "Mac Developer" certificate) and `codesign` verification claims everything is fine. `spctl` on my machine or trying to run the application on someone else's machine however results in rejection.

I tried adding `--deep` and `--force` to the code signing, but this did not solve the problem.

How does the process on the Oracle page above have to be adapted to work on 10.9?

Answer (score 2):

Code signing changed in Mavericks. There are a number of observations on the sister site:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-signing

Comment: Good idea. I had a look, but if the answer is there I couldn't find it.